# infinite-ajax-scroll not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use [infinite-ajax-scroll](https://github.com/webcreate/infinite-ajax-scroll/blob/master/demo/page1.html) for my image loading.

This is my code

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>  
<script src="{$this->scriptFolder}jqueryui.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://raw.github.com/webcreate/infinite-ajax-scroll/master/dist/jquery-ias.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    alert('in to');
        jQuery.ias({
            container : '.slider',
            item: '.thumbnails',
            pagination: '#outertt .pagination',
            next: '.pager_check',
            loader: '<img src="https://raw.github.com/webcreate/infinite-ajax-scroll/master/dist/images/loader.gif"/>',
            triggerPageThreshold: 2
        });
    });
</script>
```

This code is as per the demo code they provided.
But I get an error:

```
 Uncaught TypeError: Object function (e,n){return new x.fn.init(e,n,t)} has no method 'ias'
```

Anyone know this?

Comment: Can you post some sample HTML as well, possibly in the form of a jsfiddle link?

Comment: It seems like jQuery UI is not loaded properly. There is a good chance that this is the problem.

Comment: Well, then there was an error in the definition of that method. Are you sure the plugin file got properly loaded and executed?

Comment: http://staging.delhipress.thewinkstore.com/ this is my developing site

Comment: yes, when i look up in console all plugin files are loaed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check the console of any browser for this, it throws this error because below JS not loaded properly.

```
https://raw.github.com/webcreate/infinite-ajax-scroll/master/dist/jquery-ias.js
```

Reason: Mime Type issue.

I suggest you to download the JS file, and reference it from your local and it will work.